# Operador or en blade php

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Estoy trabajando en una plantilla blade en laravel y quiero ocultar el menu dependiento del rol del usuario. Pero no me acepta el operador or, en blade esta así:

```html
@if(! auth()->user()->is_magaly || ! auth()->user()->is_students)
    <li>
        <a href="grupos.php">Grupos</a>
    </li>
@endif
```

En pantalla todavia me muestra la opción. El módelo tengo estas 2 funciones para identificar el rol:

```php
public function getIsStudentsAttribute($value)
{
    return $this->role == "4";
}

public function getIsMagalyAttribute($value)
{
    return $this->role == "5";
}
```

Cómo puedo hacer para que desaparesca la opción si son esos roles?

Comment: las condiciones están mal entonces , ya que el operador or `||` si funciona en blade haz un dd en la vista `{{dd(auth()->user()->is_magaly)}}`, para ver si te trae algun dato , hazlo antes del if

Comment: El atributo role es un entero o una cadena en su BD ?

Comment: Probaste con un `elseif`?  https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#if-statements

Comment: podrías crear un método que sea algo como `public function canGrupos() { return in_array([ 4, 5 ] , $this->role->pluck('id')) }` y en blade podrías llamar a ese método en el if haciendo `@if($user->canGrupos()) ... @endif`  
¿Estás seguro que el método se llama **"role"**?

Comment: Hola Dev.Joel es una cadena.

Comment: Es algo raro pero cuando cambie el || por && me lo acepta y me oculta la opción cuando el usuario es magaly. Pero no se si es correcto dejarlo así

Answer (score 1):

Te sigue mostrando la opción por como declaraste la condición con los negativos.

En vez de lo que tienes

```html
@if(! auth()->user()->is_magaly || ! auth()->user()->is_students)
```

Debería ser ésta la condición para que el menú solo sea visible si no es rol 4 o 5

```html
@if( !(auth()->user()->is_magaly || auth()->user()->is_students) )
```

O bien podrías quitar el negativo usando @unless(condición) para que sea más legible. Es lo mismo que poner @if(!(condición))

```html
@unless( auth()->user()->is_magaly || auth()->user()->is_students )
    <li>
        <a href="grupos.php">Grupos</a>
    </li>
@endunless
```